# Making a simple login function. How to implement Sizeof in the for loop? and what is struct?

Tags: c

This is the login function that I made. Just so you know I'm a beginner only learned C programming a few days ago.

```
int login();

int login()
{
    int i, att, num_i, status;
    att = 1;
    status = 0;
    num_i = 999;
    char* id[100], * pass[100];
    char* inp_id[100], inp_pass[100];
    id[0] = "id1"; ///Sample ID
    id[1] = "id2";
    id[2] = "id3";
    pass[0] = "pass1"; ///Sample pass 
    pass[1] = "pass2";
    pass[2] = "pass3";
    while (att <= 3)
    {
        printf("ID:");
        scanf("%s", &inp_id);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) /// I wanted this to repeat accordingly to the size of ID that was stored
        {
            if (strcmp(inp_id, id[i]) == 0) /// Cuz when I declare i > 100 when it call for i[4] and it doesn't exist, error occured.
            {
                num_i = i;
                break; /// wanted it to break out of the loop once it got the id that's similar to what was entered
            }
        }
        printf("Password:");
        scanf("%s", &inp_pass);
        if (num_i < 100)
        {
            if (strcmp(inp_pass, pass[num_i]) == 0)///checking pass according to the positon of i on the ID
            {
                status = 1;
                att = 999;
            }
        }
        att++;
    }
    if ((att > 3) && (att < 999))
        {
            printf("Max attempt reached");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int login_status, ch;
        login_status = login();
        if (login_status == 1)
        {
            printf("---Welcome---");
            ch = options1();
        }
        else {
            printf("\nDO NOT TRY TO ENTER IF YOU'RE UNAUTHORIZED!");
        }
    }
```

So I posted a question regarding implementing sizeof() syntax into the for loop, which in the end triggered some unknown error that I don't know why or how.

A guy answered "Try a different approach. A more normal way of doing something like this is to define a struct with login entries, then declare an array with a NULL entry at the end, and use a while loop to go over them."

And then he posted few lines of code which again I don't understand

```
struct account {
    char *id;
    char *pass;
};

static const struct account account_list[] = {
    { .id = "id1", .pass = "pass1" },
    { .id = "id2", .pass = "pass2" },
    { .id = "id3", .pass = "pass3" },
    { NULL },
};

struct account *a;

for (a = account_list; a.id; a++) {
    ....
}
```

can someone explain it to me? What is the guy trying to explain? or maybe any solution for the sizeof()?

Comment: Your posted code doesn't contain `sizeof`. What is "sizeof() syntax"?

Comment: `char* inp_id[100], inp_pass[100];`, `scanf("%s", &inp_id);`, and `scanf("%s", &inp_pass);` are wrong. They should be `char inp_id[100], inp_pass[100];`, `scanf("%99s", inp_id);`, and `scanf("%99s", inp_pass);` (allocate not pointer but character array, no extra `&`, limit input length to avoid buffer overrun)

Comment: Unfortunately you have so many fundamental problems and concepts you don't understand that Stack Oveflow is probably not a good forum to get help. If possible, would suggest seek in person help from your teaching staff. It seems the core issue you are trying to solve is "repeat accordingly to the size of ID that was stored". The suggestion given to you is to store an "end" marker to tell you where the list finishes. The loop given to you goes through the `account_list` until the end marker, a NULL `id`, is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

You have N set of credentials. You are using two arrays of N elements, where the elements of one array is one of the credentials and the elements of the array is the other.

I call what you used "parallel arrays", and it's something I also try to avoid because doing any modifications to the list of elements (adding an element, removing an element) requires performing the operation on multiple times (once for each array). This is error prone, and it should therefore be avoided.

Instead, they are recommending that you use one array of N elements, where each element is a struct with both credentials. This is a less error-prone approach.

---

Where you need the size of the array, you use a literal `3`.

This is a horrible practice in any language! It should be avoided because it's extremely error-prone.

It's quite common to use a variable to track the size of the array, but they used a different approach in their suggestion. They used a [sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) to indicate the end of the array. There is an extra element element after the last one with an `id` field set to `NULL`. When you reach this, you know you've scanned the whole array. They've demonstrated this with the loop they provided. This is also a perfectly acceptable approach.

---

They also provided a cleaner way to initialize an array, but that is secondary to the above.